# 2d matrix histogram in matlab that interprets each column as a separate element

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a 128 x 100 matrix in matlab, where each column should be treated as a separate element. Lets call this matrix M.

I have another 128 x 2000 matrix(called V) composed of columns from matrix M.

How would I make a histogram that maps the frequency of each column being used in the second matrix?

```
hist(double(V),double(M)) gives the error:

 Error using histc
Edge vector must be monotonically
non-decreasing.
```

what should I be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. We start with data that resembles what you described

```
%# a matrix of 100 columns
M = rand(128,100);
sz = size(M);

%# a matrix composed of randomly selected columns of M (with replacement)
V = M(:,randi([1 sz(2)],[1 2000]));
```

Then:

```
%# map the columns to indices starting at 1
[~,~,idx] = unique([M,V]', 'rows', 'stable');
idx = idx(sz(2)+1:end);

%# count how many times each column occurs
count = histc(idx, 1:sz(2));

%# plot histogram
bar(1:sz(2), count, 'histc')
xlabel('column index'), ylabel('frequency')
set(gca, 'XLim',[1 sz(2)])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> [Lia,Locb] = [ismember(A,B,'rows')](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) also returns a vector, Locb,
>   containing the highest index in B for each row in A that is also a row
>   in B. The output vector, Locb, contains 0 wherever A is not a row of
>   B.

`ismember` with the `rows` argument can identify which row of one matrix the rows of another matrix come from.  Since it works on rows, and you are looking for columns, just transpose both matrices.

```
[~,Locb]=ismember(V',M');
histc(Locb)
```